# Build boost with b2 and linker options

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build boost with the following commandline (boost 1.63). The pared down version of what I'm doing is below. I'm seeing the same warning in Visual Studio 2010.

> b2.exe -a toolset=msvc-14.0 runtime-link=static threading=multi address-model=32 linkflags="/LTCG" cxxflags="/GL" variant=release

A warning in my output suggests that the linkflags is not being respected.

> LINK : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with 
>   LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance

This leads me to believe that any option I'm passing in for linkflags won't be respected. Does anyone know if my syntax is incorrect, or if there is a better way I should be doing this?